# Find command in Linux with -print flag

Tags: find, command

I was reading different flags of find command in Linux when I saw [here (#7)](https://www.tecmint.com/35-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command/) the following command:

```
find . -type f -perm 0777 -print
```

I checked the man page of find command but still cannot figure out what the `-print` does.  I would appreciate it if you could explain it to me.

Comment: It tells it to print the names of any matching files. It's also the default action if no other is given.

Comment: Documentation is freely available. See `man find` and search for `-print`